# How long would it take for a steel can to decompose in a landfill?

Tags: decomposition

How long would it take for a steel can to decompose in a landfill (no oxygen, no sun)? For how long would tin protect it, and for how long would it hold together afterward?

Don't close it for a lack of research. I did try to google it (including carrying out a search on Scholar) but was unable to find a claim with an authoritative source backing it. I need a good reference

Comment: You might find a better answer by posting to [Sustainable Living SE](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Spencer which SE is the most suitable for this question? Physics, maybe? Sustainable Living is not the right pick, I believe

Answer (score 2):

Depends, thin steel like auto sheet metal would mostly be gone in about 20 years buried near the surface in a location with generous rain fall. If thicker, with limited oxygen it could be around for many centuries, eg ship hulls like the Titanic in deep water. About the only data I find shows pit depth of roughly 0.125" in 5 years buried in clay soil. No data for sheet metal because no one buries it deliberately. Thicker steel like pipelines are coated and catholically protected, so any number is only an estimate.

Comment: I need a reference though

Answer (score 0):

Steel rusts. However this corrosion affects surface in any case; over time takes many years/decades to fully assimilate the whole piece. In a landfill without exposure to oxygen high quality steels may last indefinitely.

Comment: This does not account for the potential of water moisture in landfill & its ability to rust buried steel.

Comment: I looked in  ASM Metals Handbook 9th ed., volume 13 - Corrosion. Very little data as there is no application for the data.

Comment: @blacksmith37 what does it say?